# Displaying \checkmark in latex table

Tags: r, latex, knitr, xtable

In an old `.Rnw` file I was using the `RODBC` package to read an excel sheet and display a latex table containing checkmarks.

Recently, I tried to change the way I used to read the excel file, and use the `XLConnect` package instead of `RODBC`, but I came across a problem. I can't make the checkmark symbol be displayed correctly anymore. Note that the object I pass to xtable for printing is identical with the previous one, but the result is not!

Get here [the excel file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iiOMeBysVCo-rwjMdMlqa2R4CAP6x19p) that I use.

This is the working `.Rnw`. (I know the code isn't by no means optimal). The file encoding is UTF-8, and I weave the file using `knitr` and `XeLaTeX`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{bbding} % checkmark symbol
\setmainfont[Scale=1.0]{Times New Roman} % Times New Roman
\setsansfont{Times New Roman}

<<eval=TRUE,echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,error=FALSE>>=
library(plyr)
library(XLConnect)
library(lubridate)
library(RODBC)
library(stringr)
library(xtable)
library(magrittr)
@

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

{\small
<<eval=TRUE,echo=FALSE,results='asis',warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,error=FALSE>>=

sheet = 'DATA-BOOK.xls' 
con = odbcConnectExcel2007(sheet)
tbls = sqlTables(con)
df <- sqlQuery(con,"SELECT * FROM `r-crosstab$`",stringsAsFactors =FALSE)
close(con)


dfr <- df[,2:ncol(df)]
for (i in 1:ncol(dfr)){
  dfr[i][is.na(dfr[i])] <- ""
}

temp <- adply(dfr,1,function(x) length(x[x!=""]))

dfr <-  apply(dfr,2,function(x) gsub("\\?","\\\\Checkmark",x))

aitia <- paste0("c",1:nrow(dfr))
aitia <- unlist(sapply(aitia,function(x) if (nchar(x) == 2) {x=paste0(str_sub(x, 1, 1),"0",str_sub(x, 2, 2))} else{x} ))
names(aitia)<-NULL
dfr <- cbind(aitia,dfr,temp[ncol(temp)])

dfr1 <- t(dfr)
dfr1 <- apply(dfr1,2,as.character)
rownames(dfr1) <- c(colnames(dfr)[1:(length(colnames(dfr))-1)],"Αθρ.")
colnames(dfr1) <- dfr1[1,]
dfr1 <- dfr1[-1,]

dfr1[nrow(dfr1),] <- paste0("\\textbf{",dfr1[nrow(dfr1),],"}")

print(xtable(dfr1, align=paste0("l|",paste(rep("c|",length(aitia)),collapse="")),
             label='tab_crosstab'), 
      scalebox=0.80, 
      include.rownames=TRUE, 
      hline.after=c(-1:nrow(dfr1)),
      sanitize.text.function = function(x){x}
)

@
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

That's what I get when I compile it (it is the expected result)

[image]

That is the .Rnw where I face the problem. Can you tell me what I need to change?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{bbding} % checkmark symbol
\setmainfont[Scale=1.0]{Times New Roman} % Times New Roman
\setsansfont{Times New Roman}

<<eval=TRUE,echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,error=FALSE>>=
library(plyr)
library(XLConnect)
library(lubridate)
library(RODBC)
library(stringr)
library(xtable)
library(magrittr)
@

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

{\small
<<eval=TRUE,echo=FALSE,results='asis',warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,error=FALSE>>=

wb <- loadWorkbook('DATA-BOOK.xls', create = FALSE)
df <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet="r-crosstab", check.names=FALSE)

df %>%
dplyr::select(- dplyr::contains("ΑITIO")) %>%
names() -> vnames 

df[vnames] %<>%
dplyr::mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)


dfr <- df[,2:ncol(df)]
for (i in 1:ncol(dfr)){
  dfr[i][is.na(dfr[i])] <- ""
}

temp <- adply(dfr,1,function(x) length(x[x!=""]))

dfr <-  apply(dfr,2,function(x) gsub("√","\\\\Checkmark",x)) # √   <U+221A>

aitia <- paste0("c",1:nrow(dfr))
aitia <- unlist(sapply(aitia,function(x) if (nchar(x) == 2) {x=paste0(str_sub(x, 1, 1),"0",str_sub(x, 2, 2))} else{x} ))
names(aitia)<-NULL
dfr <- cbind(aitia,dfr,temp[ncol(temp)])

dfr1 <- t(dfr)
dfr1 <- apply(dfr1,2,as.character)
rownames(dfr1) <- c(colnames(dfr)[1:(length(colnames(dfr))-1)],"Αθρ.")
colnames(dfr1) <- dfr1[1,]
dfr1 <- dfr1[-1,]

dfr1[nrow(dfr1),] <- paste0("\\textbf{",dfr1[nrow(dfr1),],"}")

print(xtable(dfr1, align=paste0("l|",paste(rep("c|",length(aitia)),collapse="")),
             label='tab_crosstab'), 
      scalebox=0.80, 
      include.rownames=TRUE, 
      hline.after=c(-1:nrow(dfr1)),
      sanitize.text.function = function(x){x}
)
@
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Here is how the compliled pdf looks like now: [image]

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Greek_Greece.1253 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Greek_Greece.1253   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Greek_Greece.1253
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                 
[5] LC_TIME=Greek_Greece.1253    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] magrittr_1.5         extrafont_0.17      
 [3] xtable_1.8-3         stringr_1.3.1       
 [5] RODBC_1.3-15         lubridate_1.7.4     
 [7] XLConnect_0.2-15     XLConnectJars_0.2-15
 [9] plyr_1.8.4           tidyr_0.8.2         
[11] dplyr_0.7.7         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.19     Rttf2pt1_1.3.7   rstudioapi_0.8  
 [4] bindr_0.1.1      tidyselect_0.2.5 R6_2.3.0        
 [7] rlang_0.3.0.1    tools_3.5.1      extrafontdb_1.0 
[10] yaml_2.2.0       assertthat_0.2.0
```

**EDIT**

In the following pair of code snipets I tried to minimize the examples, leaving out some irrelevant parts. Again, the first is the one that works ok. In the meantime I noticed that no matter what string I use as a replacement in `gsub` (in the second example), the result is always the same!!!

Working code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{bbding} % checkmark symbol
\setmainfont[Scale=1.0]{Times New Roman} % Times New Roman
\setsansfont{Times New Roman}

<<eval=TRUE,echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,error=FALSE>>=
library(XLConnect)
library(RODBC)
library(xtable)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
@

\begin{document}

{\small
<<eval=TRUE,echo=FALSE,results='asis',warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,error=FALSE>>=

sheet = 'DATA-BOOK.xls' 
con = odbcConnectExcel2007(sheet)
tbls = sqlTables(con)
df <- sqlQuery(con,"SELECT * FROM `r-crosstab$`",stringsAsFactors =FALSE)
close(con)

df %>%
dplyr::select(- dplyr::contains("ΑITIO")) %>%
names() -> vnames 

df[vnames] %<>%
mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% 
mutate_if(is.character, funs(coalesce(., "")))
names(df)[1] <- "TITLE"

dfr <-  apply(df,2,function(x) gsub("\\?","\\\\Checkmark",x))
rownames(dfr) <- NULL
dfr1 <- t(dfr)
dfr1[1,] <- paste0("c",1:19)

print(xtable(dfr1), 
      scalebox=0.80, 
      hline.after=c(-1:nrow(dfr1)),
      sanitize.text.function = function(x){x}
)
@
}

\end{document}
```

NOT working code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{bbding} % checkmark symbol
\setmainfont[Scale=1.0]{Times New Roman} % Times New Roman
\setsansfont{Times New Roman}

<<eval=TRUE,echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,error=FALSE>>=
library(XLConnect)
library(RODBC)
library(xtable)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
@

\begin{document}

{\small
<<eval=TRUE,echo=FALSE,results='asis',warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,error=FALSE>>=

wb <- loadWorkbook('DATA-BOOK.xls', create = FALSE)
df <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet="r-crosstab", check.names=FALSE)

df %>%
dplyr::select(- dplyr::contains("ΑITIO")) %>%
names() -> vnames 

df[vnames] %<>%
mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% 
mutate_if(is.character, funs(coalesce(., "")))
names(df)[1] <- "TITLE"

dfr <-  apply(df,2,function(x) gsub("√","\\\\Checkmark",x)) # √   <U+221A>
dfr1 <- t(dfr)
dfr1[1,] <- paste0("c",1:19)

print(xtable(dfr1), 
      scalebox=0.80, 
      include.rownames=TRUE, 
      hline.after=c(-1:nrow(dfr1)),
      sanitize.text.function = function(x){x}
)
@
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This might be a *reproducible* example, but it is far from being a *minimal* example. Could you try to isolate the problem and leave out the irrelevant parts? You don't need hundreds of cells, colnames, rownames, and a bunch of packages to check how a checkmark is displayed.

Comment: @CL. I edited to add a pair of examples not so far from being  minimal.

Comment: @GeorgeDontas I ran your code on MaxOSX Mojave with and it produced the right results with R 3.5.1. Let me run the same setup on Windows 10. to see if I get different results. I get a sense this is a Windows font issue...
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yg71jryn6r3gc80/53243041v1.pdf?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the formatting of your `gsub` line.

#### Proposed Solution:

Replace:

`dfr <-  apply(df,2,function(x) gsub("√","\\\\Checkmark",x)) # √   <U+221A>`

with

`dfr <-  apply(dfr,2,function(x) gsub("\u221A","\\\\Checkmark",x)) #  √   <U+221A>`

#### Result:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/evzknzobfwh0ag1/53243041v2.pdf?dl=0

#### Setup:

I tested this on Windows 10, with RStudio and R3.5.1, using knitr and XeLatex for typesetting.

#### Explanation:

The .rnw file when compiled creates an intermediate .tex file as output, this is then converted to pdf. You have to pass the code `\u221A"` in the correct format through to the pdf formatting application.